# How to pass a workspace url as a parameter to the repository in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to pass the string representation of a nodeRef as a parameter to the repository like so:
  `url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "synapture/commande/commande-get/" + new Alfresco.util.NodeRef(commandeObj.commandeNodeRef)`

however when I look at the debugger and output the **url.templateArgs.** on the repository side the first '/' after workspace is stripped.

Comment: Can you give the result of Alfresco.util.NodeRef(commandeObj.commandeNodeRef) & just commandeObj.commandeNodeRef ?

Comment: They were both fine on inspection in the browser javascript debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input auf Alfresco.util.NodeRef should be a string in NodeRef-Format, e.g. workspaces://SpacesStore/02f....
return value is a JS object that constains amongst others a property 'uri'
So, if commandeObj.commandeNodeRef is a String in NodeRef-Format, then the following code will do the job (add '.uri' to get the NodeRef in URI format):

```
url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "synapture/commande/commande-get/" + new Alfresco.util.NodeRef(commandeObj.commandeNodeRef).uri
```

Your Backend-Webscript (*desc.xml)should be defined as following (by the way, that's not a nice RESTful URL ;-)):

```
synapture/commande/commande-get/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}
```

Inside your Backend Webscript:

```
 var storeType = url.templateArgs.store_type,
 storeId = url.templateArgs.store_id,
 id = url.templateArgs.id,
 nodeRef = storeType + "://" + storeId + "/" + id,
 node = utils.getNodeFromString(nodeRef);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at actions.js (web-client JavaScript file) you'll see the following:

```
var jsNode = record.jsNode,
            nodeRef = jsNode.isLink ? jsNode.linkedNode.nodeRef : jsNode.nodeRef,
strNodeRef = nodeRef.toString()........
```

The url is then being used at an action:
**documentDetailsUrl: fnPageURL("document-details?nodeRef=" + strNodeRef),**

The object recordd.jsNode is defined elsewhere:

```
record.jsNode = new Alfresco.util.Node(response.json.item.node);
```

So probably you could do the following in your case:
1. just add the toString() to the newly created Alfresco.Util.NodeRef object.
2. If that doesn't work, create a Alfresco.util.Node and do a toString()